# Create relative hyperlinks in Excel for a specified path using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, relative-path

I have a pandas DataFrame, with one column `FullPath` containing the directory tree listing of a specified path. I am saving this to an Excel spreadsheet:

```
FullPath

C:\Users\aaron\folder1              
C:\Users\aaron\folder1\191090-MS-0001_1.pdf
C:\Users\aaron\folder1\folder3              
C:\Users\aaron\folder1\folder3\191090-MS-0001_1.pdf
C:\Users\aaron\folder2              
C:\Users\aaron\folder2\191090-MS-0005_1.pdf
```

I would like to change the values under `FullPath` so that (A) they appear as hyperlinks within the spreadsheet and (B) they are relative links.

Is this possible?

The Python code to generate this is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def dir_tree(root):
    """Create list of all file/folder paths"""
    dir_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for d in dirs:
            dir_list.append(os.path.join(root, d))
        for f in files:
            dir_list.append(os.path.join(root, f))
    return dir_list

# Target directory
PATH = r'C:\Users\aaron'

# Dataframe of directory tree
dir_tree_df = pd.DataFrame({"FullPath" : dir_tree(PATH)})

# Output to Excel
dir_tree_df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

EDIT:

Some context on what I'm trying to do - basically the Python script to generate this will be run on SSDs containing files/folders (I'll just update the `PATH` variable in the script above before running), and the resulting Excel will be stored within that SSD.

The idea is that someone plugs the SSD into their machine, opens up the Excel file within it, and then can click on any of the paths under `FullPath` and it'll open that folder, or attempt to open the file within the SSD.

Also - I've discovered that the below will actually convert the links to hyperlink when outputted to Excel. However my concern is that the full path of SSDs will change depending on the machine, if I'm not mistaken (the drive letters)? Is there a way for me to accommodate this?

```
dir_tree_df['FullPath'] = '=HYPERLINK("' + dir_tree_df['FullPath'] + '")'
```

Comment: The Excel HYPERLINK function accepts references relative to the file's current directory. Suppose you save your file in `C:\Users\aaron`, then this should remain a valid ref for your first pdf above: `=HYPERLINK("folder1\191090-MS-0001_1.pdf")`.

Comment: Ahh okay. I didn't know that. That helps. I suppose then all I'd really need to do is remove the `C:\Users\Aaron` part from the `FullPath` column and use the same line of code I added to my EDIT section above

Comment: Yes, almost. You need to remove "C:\Users\Aaron\". So including the final backslash. "=HYPERLINK("\folder1\ etc")" won't work.

Comment: Also, just a general warning: it is not possible to have two Excel Workbooks with the same name open at the same time. E.g. if you have your `C:\Users\aaron\output.xlsx` and a link like `=HYPERLINK("folder1\output.xlsx")`, then your user will run into an error trying to open the file from the link.

Comment: Thanks @ouroboros1. It seems to work. Only thing is, all my hyperlinks are opening up in my Browser. I think because my org uses OneDrive. Are you aware of anyway to force Excel to open the links in a file browser?

Comment: I think issue is I need to specify the full path for files to open in the relevant applications, rather than the browser. So I really need to concat the new column I've created onto the end of the current workbooks path, if possible.

Comment: For me it makes no diff: all links to files on OneDrive are getting opened in browser. Extremely annoying. I saw this: in Excel, open File ->  Options -> Advanced, at Link Handling, check "Open supported hyperlinks etc...". Isn't doing anything,  even after restart. If you think adding the complete path will make a diff, try the links like this: `=HYPERLINK(LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)&"folder1\file1.xlsx")` where `LEFT(...-1)` should resolve to wb location (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3188-excel-get-workbook-location.html).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there's a setting in Excel. They are opening okay with the full path for me. I'm trying to implement that formula in Python `dir_tree_df['Test'] = ('=HYPERLINK(CONCAT(LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1),"' + dir_tree_df['Path'] + '"))' % ( ))` but in Excel it adds an `@` just before `CONCAT` which is breaking it.

Comment: Ok got around that by just using `&` rather than `CONCAT`